# Cannot update/edit any file

Tags: permissions

Hello friends I cannot update any file under the file system. It says you do not have permissions. I tried to edit files using gedit but it gives me this error... How can I update files in the file system.

I am the admin.

Thanks

Comment: Where in the file system do you want to edit those files? What do you mean with "I am the admin"?

Comment: Post the output of `groups <your_username>` in your question. Do you have the root password?

Comment: Yes I have it.
O/P - shivamd adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the *Windows* security approach, system files cannot be modified on Ubuntu without proper authorization. You need to type the **root** password. In order to do the changes you want —provided that you know what you are doing—, open a terminal and type this:

```
gksudo gedit NAME-OF-THE-FILE
```

Remember to type the full path, for instance:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/index.theme
```

Be careful with these commands: `gksudo` or `sudo`, because you can spoil your system.

Answer (score 1):

Command to change the owner and group owner of the directory and all subdirectories with files:

```
chown -R user:group /home/user/dir/
```

The right of access:
run - 1, change - 2 reading - 4

```
chmod -R 700 /home/user
```

Change permissions only to files or only folders:

```
find /home/user -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

or 660 instead of 600

```
find /home/user -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

or 770 instead of 700
if you want to give permission to the group